# Why is my graph being plot this way in python.matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm creating a mini project in which, the user enters the marks of a student and accordingly, those marks are plot in a graph. The marks entered are stored in the list "Student.marks", and Student here is an object of the class 'student'.
I want to have a **'fixed' y-axis ranging from 0-100**, and want to plot the marks which are entered by the user. Please help me out.

**Here's the output upon executing the code.**

```
How many students' reports would you like?: 1  
Hello! What's your name? : Steven  
What are the grades in your following subjects? (%):  
English: 79  
Science: 68  
Maths: 98  
Computers: 57
```

[image: This is the graph I get upon running the code.]

**Here's the code:**

```
class student:
subs = ['English', 'Science', 'Maths', 'Computers'] 

def subMarks(self):
    i = 0
    eng_marks = 0
    cs_marks = 0
    sci_marks = 0
    math_marks = 0

    self.marks = [eng_marks, sci_marks, math_marks, cs_marks]       
    print("What are the grades in your following subjects? (%): ")

    for k in range(len(self.marks)):
        self.marks[k] = input(student.subs[i]+': ')

        if int(self.marks[k]) < 0 or int(self.marks[k]) > 100:
            print("Invalid Marks. Please try again later.")
            break

        i += 1


while d<num:
    name = input('Hello! What\'s your name? : ') 
    Student = student()
    Student.subMarks()


    fig1, ax = plt.subplots()


    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.title('Marks of Students')
    ax.plot(student.subs, Student.marks, marker = 'o', label=name)
    ax.set(ylim = (0,100))
    plt.legend()

    d+=1

plt.show()
```

Comment: Apart from the big no-no of posting code as image instead of as text, a lot is missing to reproduce the problem.  The most probably cause would be that the y-values are in text format. They need to be converted to numbers.

Comment: Hello @JohanC! Thanks for helping out. I tried to convert the y-values to numbers, yet I get the same graph, the only difference being that the graph starts from the origin. 

Another plausible solution would highly be appreciated!

Comment: please share the code for your `student` class, in particular the `subMarks` function. Also, is it a typo that you use the lower-case `student.subs` for the x-values and the upper-case `Student.marks` for the y-values?

Comment: I have added the code for my 'Student' Class. Kindly have a look at it , and ignore any redundancy in code as this is a draft project.

Comment: @JohanC, I had done it in the number format but it hadn't worked out.That's why I have removed that part...maybe I might've used the wrong logic.

Comment: @tmdavison, 'Student' here is an object, while 'student' is the name of the class.    'subMarks' is a method of the 'Student' class.

Comment: Why not `self.marks[k] = int(input(student.subs[i]+': '))` ? Note that the result of `input(...)` is a string, which you assign to `self.marks[k]`. You should convert that string to a number (int or float).

Comment: @JohanC, Thank you so very much for helping me to figure out this mistake!!! It works as I wanted it to work! Truly Grateful!